# Achievements shows bogus reputation points

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, achievements-dialog

Looking at the detail of my Achievements from the dropdown, I found an entry with +290. Wondering what that was all about, I looked into my Reputation history and found that entry with +10. Something's going weird as the reputation points do not match.
[image: The reputation points that showed up in achievements do not match what I actually got.]

Comment: Had you ever looked at that tab before? If it's the first time it should show your whole rep history.

Comment: It's not bogus, you have earned 300 rep for that question. Your blue line shows you earned 10 on Jan 9th. The dropdown says 290 since you last looked at the dropdown. There's no requirement for those two numbers to be the same.

Comment: @waxeagle I generally look at this tab each time I get a Reputation increase. It's possible that I haven't looked at it in a few weeks, but this isn't the first time.

Answer (score 6):

You're equating a summary with a single entry, this is not correct.  You have 30 upvotes for [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655738/net-cultureinfo-how-to-get-country-name/3674907#3674907).  290 points of those were "recent".

The summary algorithm gets the latest `n` entries and summarizes them by date range. For a user without a ton of activity date to date, this can span a wide time range...as it does here.

Comment: That makes sense. I obviously thought there was a correlation. Now I know better.